# In C# what does it mean to get a System.Exception: IP Out Of Range?

Tags: c#, http

When attempting to use `HttpClient` to post async I received an aggregate system exception that included the error `System.Exception: IP Out Of Range`. I am able to make the same call from a different machine without issue, what would cause this?

Note that the IP address is being resolved through the DNS, a url is provided to the function.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `IP Out Of Range` is a custom exception and therefore this is not generic. It will be specific to your code or a library your using

Comment: code sample would be good addition to this question, and error stack trace

Comment: @Liam the library is System.Net.Http, I mean, that's  the biggest web library there is.

Comment: @Vladimir everything after "System.Exception: IP Out of Range" is completely tied up in my own code. Line numbers and custom method names, I don't think it would be very illuminating.

Comment: I don't beleiev that `System.Net.Http` will trigger this error. Perhaps if you can show how you trigger this error?

Comment: `var result = await httpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage).ConfigureAwait(false);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are receiving this error from only one machine you should check with your endpoint's host to see if you're being blocked. Having your IP address blacklisted would cause this error.

Comment: [It's perfectly valid to answer your own question immediately.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: Thank you @Liam it is allowed and encouraged. I could not find a question with an answer asking this. It took me a long time to find the answer. So I put it out there for other people to see. Sorry for inconveniencing you guys.